# Recursive Number Addition

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having trouble with what appears to be a rouge total variable. The goal of the sumDigits function is to add each digit of the users input recursively to a total that will then be displayed. What I find is now as I pass the reference to input total also takes in that value. Could I get an explanation on whats going on?

My code broken down into simple statements:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumDigits(int&);

int main()
{
int input = 123;
cout << sumDigits(input);
}

int sumDigits(int& input)
{
int total, newNumber;
if (input < 10)
return input;
else
{
newNumber = input%10;
total += newNumber;
input = input/10;
return sumDigits(input);
}
}
```

My code while testing to verify total: https://pastebin.com/u1MS63Ji

Results from current code:

```
Welcome to the Sum of Digits Machine. Please type in your number or -1 to 
quit
enter a nonnegative integer: 1234
input: 1234 
Total: 1234  // total magically takes input value
newNumber: 0
Total: 1234
Total after: 1238 newNumber: 4  //total+=newNumber does its job.
input: 123
input: 123
Total: 1539161746 //how in the world? 1238 + 3 does not equal this....
newNumber: 32600
Total: 1539161746
Total after: 1539161749 newNumber: 3
input: 12
input: 12
Total: 1539161746
newNumber: 32600
Total: 1539161746
Total after: 1539161748 newNumber: 2
input: 1
input: 1
number is smaller than 10
the sum of all digits is: 1.
enter a nonnegative integer:
```

Could someone explain to me why total is taking in inputs value at the start of sumDigits()? Also any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: hopefully this clarification fixed my onHold. If not admins please tell me exactly what you're wanting as I'm new to stack overflow obviously. I should also explain for the down votes I am attempting to research the problem, but am not having the best of luck. I'm still a student and new to this.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I'm using Cloud 9 which has a native debugger in it. I've traced it twice and still cant figure out where it is getting mixed up.

Comment: Put your code here, not on "pastebin".  Those links can go dead at any time, making this question worthless in the future.  Take out the comments, `cout`'s,  and empty lines for starters.

Comment: As an example [this is what your code reduces down to](http://ideone.com/I84rzz), thus it would be a [mcve].  Now, using that, we aren't scrolling through scores of unnecessary comments and superfluous `cout` lines.  In addition, **you** may find the problem with the code presented this way.

Comment: Gotcha. I kind of threw up my hands at it earlier hence why I put it up at its current state. Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is "normal" (ie. standard) c++. I also check only new code.

Minor issues: you're using unitialized variables:
- you're testing while loop on unitialized variable in line 27,
- you're printing unitialized variable in line 82 and 83,

Get into habit of always initializing variables, like:

```
int total = 0, newNumber = 0;
```

Now to algorithm: it's wrong. Consider lines 82 - 90:
84: you calculate digit value, good.
86: you add digit value to total, which would be good if total would be initialized. But since you're going to initialize total to zero, then addition is not neccesary.
88: you calculate input for recursive call, which is good. You're using the variable passed to you by your caller by reference, which in recursive algorithms is tricky, but let's stick with it.
90: you call recursively.

You havent do anything to digit value from line 84 (except adding it to another local variable)...

Try this:

```
return newNumber + sumDigits(input);
```

and use returned value (rather than input) in line 48:

```
int inputDigitSum = sumDigits(input);
```

UPDATE:
you're trying to calculate sum of digits by using recursive algorithm. Those are notoriusly tricky, hard to explain and follow. Nevertheless let's try.

Basic idea:
given some integer value (input) for which we want to calculate sum of digits, we strip a single digit from it (the lowest digit, using % operator). Then we call recursively the same function with value consisting of remaining digits (result of division by 10). That call will somehow return sum of digits for the stripped value. Then we add our digit to that value and return the sum to our caller. Or in list form:

1. let current_digit = input % 10 # current digit value
2. let remaining_value = input / 10 # remaining digits
3. let digit_sum = result of recursive call with remaining_value if its at least 10
4. return digit_sum + current_digit

Let's try this out on number input = 124:

```
 1. current_digit = 124 % 10 = 4
 2. remaining_value = 124 / 10 = 12
 3. recursive call with remaining_value = 12
 3.1. current_digit = 12 % 10 = 2
 3.2. remaining_value = 12 / 10 = 1
 3.3. recursive call with remaining_value = 1
 3.3.1. current_digit = 1 % 10 = 1
 3.3.2. remaining_value = 1 / 10 = 0
 3.3.3. no recursive call because remaining_value is less than 10
 3.3.4. return current_digit = 1
 3.4. return current_digit + call result = 2 + 1 = 3
 4. return current_digit + call result = 4 + 3 = 7
```

Now coming back to your function.

```
int sumDigits(int& input)
{
  int total, newNumber;
  if (input < 10)
    return input; // (1)
  else {
    newNumber = input%10;    // (2)
    total += newNumber;      // (3)
    input = input/10;        // (4)
    int tmp = sumDigits(input); // (5)
    return tmp;              // (6)
  }
}
```

Lets go with the same number input = 124:

```
2. newNumber = input%10 = 124%10 = 4
3. total += newNumber = random (total is unitialized, so its random + 4, still random)
4. input = input/10 = 124/10 = 12
5.2. newNumber = input%10 = 12%10 = 2
5.3. total += newNumber = random
5.4. input = input/10 = 12/10 = 1
5.4.1. return input = 1 (because its less than 10)
5.5. tmp = result of recursive call = 1
5.6. return tmp = 1
5. tmp = result of recursive call = 1
6. return tmp = 1
```

Note, that every call to sumDigits has its own private local variables total and newNumber and they aren't connected to each other in any way. This is why i suggested returning sum of newNumber (which should be called lastDigit or something like this), being least important digit and result of recursive call, which should return sum of other, remaining digits.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following you. When the variables are initialized to 0 during each recursion, it wipes out the work of adding said variables to my total as every time my total is 0. How do I keep my total out of the recursion, or better yet actually give it the ability to do the work I'm asking. It seems even if I were to add newNumber to the recursive sumDigits() it would always go right back to 0. Could you clarify what you are saying?

Comment: Also  when total was initialized to 0 it doesn't really explain how or why my total is automatically becoming input when I didn't assign it to have the value of input....

Comment: Ahh.

No, it doesnt work that way. By default function variables (both total and newNumber) are so called local. Every call to sumDigits gets its own copy of those variables. So when you call sumDigits recursively, every call has its own copy. Initializing it does not modify other "copies".